# How to enable required an input with display:none?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show the "required" alert in an input of the type "file", this is hidden (display: none) because it must have a specific style, and this style is applied to its corresponding label. Below is an example:

```html
<label for="add-photo-input" id="add-photo">Adjuntar Foto</label>
<input id="add-photo-input" type="file" required name="add-photo-input" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: You can always check if the input field has any value or not. Based on that you can show appropriate message.

Comment: Don’t use display:none, use opacity:0

Comment: @ScottMarcus, thank you very much, I solved the problem with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript.

```
<script>
function check() {
    var x = document.getElementById("add-photo-input").value;
    if (x == "") {
        document.getElementById("add-photo").style="border:.1em solid blue";
        alert("Please add photo");
        return false;
    }
} function reset() {
    document.getElementById("add-photo").style="border:none";
}
</script>
```

And make sure that the check function is called when the submit button is clicked:

```
<label for="add-photo-input" id="add-photo" onclick="reset()">Adjuntar Foto</label>
<input id="add-photo-input" type="file" required name="add-photo-input" style="display:none">
<input onclick="check()" id="submit" type="submit" />
```

It would be helpful to have more information, is there a reason you aren't able to change the style of the file input element to match what you want?